# How to programmatically import dates to many users in exchange server

Tags: excel, outlook, exchange-server

We have an enterprise MS Exchange server on the one hand and a different web-based time-management software on the other hand. In the latter the employees request vacation dates but these cannot be viewed by everyone.

So we would like to import the granted vacation dates as dates in outlook for every user, i.e. import it somehow in the Exchange server.

From the time-management software I can export Excel-Sheets month-wise, so I could read those programmatically and push that information into Exchange (e.g. via some C# program). However, I'm not in any way familiar with Exchange, and I don't know under what terms I should google this functionality.

Any hints to APIs or examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Office 365, use REST APIs.  Take a look at http://dev.outlook.com for more info including [Getting started](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet).

If this is an on-premises Exchange 2007 or later server, use [Exchange Web Services (EWS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).  Easiest way to do that is to use [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api).